# Send form based on html select error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select form that sends the value when you change the select. Unfortunately, everytime it sends it goes back to the option "10". How can I have it (for example) so you can click on the 20 option and send form and stay on 20?

Here is the code:

```
<form method='get' name='FormVote'>
     <select name="vote" onChange="document.forms['FormVote'].submit()">
             <option selected="selected" value='10'>10</option>
             <option value='20'>20</option>
             <option value='30'>30</option>
             <option value='40'>40</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's staying on 10 because of the
    selected="selected"
attribute in the option for 10

To have it remember where the user put it you'll need to fetch its value from the database and then do something like this in PHP:

```
foreach ($optionsArray as $option) {
    echo '<option ';
    if ($theOptionValue == $savedUserOptionValue)
        echo 'selected="selected"';
    echo 'value="', $theOptionValue, '>', $theOptionValue, '</option>';
}
```

Or you could use AJAX to send the form to the server in which case the page won't refresh and the option box will stay where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax or,

```
<form method='get' name='FormVote' target='hidden'>
 <select name="vote" onChange="document.forms['FormVote'].submit()">
         <option selected="selected" value='10'>10</option>
         <option value='20'>20</option>
         <option value='30'>30</option>
         <option value='40'>40</option>
 </select>
</form>
<iframe name='hidden' id='hidden' style='display:none' width='0' height='0' border='0'></iframe>
```